# CakePHP SUM of Associated Model with GROUP BY

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.2

I have an `Invoice` model that `hasMany` charges. Each time I get an Invoice, it returns all the associated charges (`Charge` is a model that `belongsTo` `Invoice`). What I would like is to also return the `SUM` of all charges per invoice.

I tried to use the following virtual field, but it returned the SUM of all Charges (not by invoice).

```
//In Charge model
public $virtualFields = array(
    'total_charges' => 'SUM(Charge.amount)'
);
```

Do I have my virtual field incorrect (I assume it needs a `GROUP BY` somewhere)? Is there a better option in my model?

I'm using CakePHP 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer by using the `afterFind` callback in my `Invoice` model. Here's the function I'm using:

```
public function afterFind($results) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($val['Charge'])) {
            $total = 0;
            foreach ($val['Charge'] as $charge) {
                $total += $charge['amount'];
            }
            $results[$key]['Invoice']['total_charges'] = $total;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken directly from the CakePHP book:

> ## Limitations of virtualFields
>
> The implementation of `virtualFields` has a few limitations. First
>   you cannot use `virtualFields` on associated models for conditions,
>   order, or fields arrays. Doing so will generally result in an SQL
>   error as the fields are not replaced by the ORM. This is because it
>   difficult to estimate the depth at which an associated model might be
>   found.
>
> A common workaround for this implementation issue is to copy
>   `virtualFields` from one model to another at runtime when you need
>   to access them::
>
> ```
> <?php
> $this->virtualFields['full_name'] = $this->Author->virtualFields['full_name'];
> ```
>
> or::
>
> ```
> <?php
> $this->virtualFields += $this->Author->virtualFields;
> ```

Instead maybe you could tally the charges with php rather than through sql?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should adjust through the afterFind callback?

Comment: I tried getting it to work through afterFind but I was having some difficulties getting it to return the correct array structure, perhaps you could play around with it but you could also just foreach($invoice['Charge'] as $charge) { $total += $charge['amount']} in the view although that is not the best solution obviously

Comment: This got me moving in the correct direction, and I have added my solution.